# Linq average query and projection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to get the average rating of people from the ratings table which I have the following code for. I'm projecting the result into PersonVm class

```
    public IEnumerable SrchArtisansByBSSLR(string q, int s = 0, int l = 0, double z = 0)
    {
        var list = from item in _entities.People
                   where item.Skill.SkillName == q && item.StateId == s && item.LGAId == l && item.Ratings.Any(g => g.RatingValue == z)
                   group item by item.PersonId into d
                   select new PersonVm
                   {
                       PersonId = d.Key,
                       Rating = d.Average(x=>x.Ratings.Any(y=>y.RatingValue)),  
                       LastName = item.LastName,
                       Skill = item.Skill.SkillName,
                       StateId = item.StateId,
                       LGAId = item.LGAId,
                       Address = item.Address,
                       Email = item.Email,
                       ImageSource = @"\Photos\" + item.ImageSource,
                       RegDate = item.RegDate                       
                   };
        return list;                   
    }
```

I'm getting the following errors

> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

and

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double?' to 'bool' ArtsHub.DataLayer

Please what is wrong with my code for getting average?

Comment: Can you try `Rating = d.Ratings.Average()`

Comment: `.Any()` returns a bool - did you mean `.First()`?

Comment: @Yahya I tried Rating = d.Ratings.Average() it can't see it as an accessible member

Comment: @RGraham  I brings these errors  1.Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<CraftzHub.Models.Rating,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type 2. Cannot implicitly convert type 'double?' to 'bool'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note `.ToList()` before `... .GroupBy(item => new ...` is caused your data be fetched in memory first, and `group by` will be done in memory, you can compare execution time of these two queries.

```
var list = _entities.People
            .Where(item => item.Skill.SkillName == q && 
                           item.StateId == s && 
                           item.LGAId == l && 
                           item.Ratings.Any(g => g.RatingValue == z))
            .ToList()
            .GroupBy(item => new 
            {
                item.PersonId,
                item.LastName,
                item.Skill.SkillName,
                item.StateId,
                item.LGAId,
                item.Address,
                item.Email,
                item.ImageSource,
                item.RegDate
            })
            .Select(d => new PersonVm() 
            {
                PersonId = d.Key,
                Rating = d.Average(x => x.Ratings.Any(y => y.RatingValue)),
                LastName = d.Key.LastName,
                Skill = d.Key.SkillName,
                StateId = d.Key.StateId,
                LGAId = d.Key.LGAId,
                Address = d.Key.Address,
                Email = d.Key.Email,
                ImageSource = @"\Photos\" + d.Key.ImageSource,
                RegDate = d.Key.RegDate
            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Hello Amir, on trying this out i was getting an error(cannot implicitly convert type double? to bool) on the Rating property (Rating=d.Average(x=>x.Ratings.Any(y=>y.RatingValue))) Then i changed it to this ( Rating = d.Average(x => x.Ratings.Sum(y => y.RatingValue)),). This works but insteading of returning average it returns the sum. Pls what do you recommend, I have tried to work my way around it to no avail...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this `x=>x.Ratings.Any(y=>y.RatingValue)` return a `bool` as result, because `.Any()` produce `boolean` result type, you need to get a `lambda` to `.Average()`, which produce a `type` same as type of `Rating` property.

it seems `Rating` is a `double?` so you need a `lambda` to be passed to `.Average()` which return a `double?` or `double` or something can be converted to `double?`

i think you need this:

```
Rating = d.Average(x => x.Ratings.Sum(y => y.RatingValue))
```

Comment: this looks so clear and logical to the eye and compiler.It worked just that after I updated the question with some other properties that I would like to access they are not accessible. Is it that after grouping I can't access 'item' again and what would you recommend?Thanks...

Comment: your question was not clear. and not me, others (in comments) had not  thought your mean is how to access to items has been grouped... finally about your question, are all these properties you included, same for every `PersonId` ?

Comment: I meant your answer was clear and that it fixed the error.Thanks. What i was saying is that after i brought in those properties i was unable to use them. For the question yes they are the same for every personId just that i'm projecting into PersonVm so that not all the columns will be selected...Thanks once more...

Comment: aha, that was a misunderstanding, because they are same for every person id, you need to add them to `group by`, i need to add another post, check that

Answer (score 0):

you need to add them to `group by`.

```
var list = from item in _entities.People

            where item.Skill.SkillName == q && item.StateId == s && item.LGAId == l && item.Ratings.Any(g => g.RatingValue == z)

            group item by new { 
                item.PersonId,
                item.LastName,
                item.Skill.SkillName,
                item.StateId,
                item.LGAId,
                item.Address,
                item.Email,
                item.ImageSource,
                item.RegDate
            } into d

            select new PersonVm
            {
                 PersonId = d.Key,
                 Rating = d.Average(x => x.Ratings.Any(y => y.RatingValue)),
                 LastName = d.Key.LastName,
                 Skill = d.Key.SkillName,
                 StateId = d.Key.StateId,
                 LGAId = d.Key.LGAId,
                 Address = d.Key.Address,
                 Email = d.Key.Email,
                 ImageSource = @"\Photos\" + d.Key.ImageSource,
                 RegDate = d.Key.RegDate
            };
return list;
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked perfectly. I was just wondering the effect this would have on performance if I'm using this to search hundreds of thousands of rows...

Comment: `group by` specially when you group your items by complex object is slow, in these case its more effective to fetch your data first and then group by in memory, by this way you can increase your performance, and execution of your query, i need to add another post to write a query which fetch data first and then do group by